# How to access/modify elements created as part of a ControlTemplate from within XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, styles, pixelsense

Skimmed through the other related questions, but I didn't see something that answered this explicit question.

(In my case, I'm working on a Microsoft Surface application, which is where a number of the classes I'm using come from)

So, I'd like to attach an ElementMenu containing a few fixed items to each ScatterViewItem in my ScatterView, which I can do like so:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuedSVITemplate" TargetType="{x:Type s:ScatterViewItem}">
  <Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
      <s:ElementMenu Name="Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" ActivationMode="AlwaysActive">
        <s:ElementMenuItem Name="MenuItemClose" Header="Close" Click="CloseItemClicked"/>
      </s:ElementMenu>
    </ContentPresenter>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And I can then create ScatterViewItems later on that use this template:

```
<ScatterViewItem Name="SomeItem" Template="{StaticResource MenuedSVITemplate"/>
```

But, what if I want to add additional items to the menu defined in the template?  Is there any way to do that in XAML?  (I know I could do it in code-behind by using Template.FindName to get the ElementMenu, downcasting, and adding my menu items programmatically.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I didn't expect this to work, but it did. Check where the ContentPresenter is:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuedSVITemplate"
                   TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
      <Menu Name="Menu"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Name="MenuItemClose"
                  Header="Close"
                  Click="CloseItemClicked" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
      </Menu>
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
  <Button Template="{StaticResource MenuedSVITemplate}">
    <MenuItem Name="MenuItemHello"
              Header="Hello" />
  </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Okay, so that's interesting - but what if I also wanted to be able to specify the content of the templated item?  e.g. if your button was a Grid, and I wanted to be able to both specify the contents of the Grid and an attached menu?  Can you somehow have a second ContentPresenter showing different content?